# Ruby on Rails 4 Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have to url **/pc/group/1** point to **views/groups/show.html.erb**. I'm not sure how to do this.
I tried the following:

```
namespace :pc do
    resources :groups
end

resources :pc
```

But it results in can't find the page.

Comment: What's the real message the server puts out?
Perhaps your controller/action doesn't exists or your view is not available.

**EDIT:** Please type `rake routes` in your terminal. The real route for this routes.rb should be **/pc/groups/1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd tell the route which controller and action to use in this situation:

```
namespace :pc, controller: 'groups' do
    resources :groups
end

resources :pc
```

Note that doing it this way, all routes for /pc/groups will point to the `GroupsController`, not just `show`.

Comment: I have the following with rake routes:
pc_group GET    /pc/groups/:id(.:format)      pc/groups#show However, when I go to the page it result in a page not found.

Comment: What is 'rat' in the above route?

Comment: Right, that's because your route shows the controller it's looking for is `Pc::Groups#show`, not `Groups#show`.

Comment: I have the following in my development.log: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Pc::GroupsController), How can I fix it?

Comment: Exactly, because your route is looking for `Pg::GroupsController` but you only have a `GroupsController` - the `Pg` in the former is the namespace in your routes.  Have you tried my change?

Comment: See my edit - I had the right idea, wrong place for the `controller` call.

Comment: No problem.  Sorry for the run around.